# How to select elements using HTML agility pack include selector element?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

How select element by class include this selector?
Example:

```html
<div class="bla">
  <p>Some text1</p>
</div>
<div class="bla">
  <p>Some text2</p>
</div>
```

if use

```
 html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='bla']")
```

then we get only
`<p>`Some Text1`</p>` and `<p>`Some text2`</p>`
I need get html include selector element like this

```
<div class="bla">
```

`<p>`Some text`</p>`

```
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep using `//div[@class='bla']` selector and get HTML markup of the corresponding `div`s from `OuterHtml` property, for example :

```
var html = @"<div>
    <div class='bla'>
      <p>Some text1</p>
    </div>
    <div class='bla'>
      <p>Some text2</p>
    </div>
</div>";
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='bla']");
foreach(HtmlNode node in nodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.OuterHtml);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

**<kbd>[Dotnetfiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oUM8Ce)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
<div class='bla'>
      <p>Some text1</p>
    </div>

<div class='bla'>
      <p>Some text2</p>
    </div>
```